# Magento2 rest api how to add product?

Tags: magento2

```
<?
//Authentication rest API magento2.Please change url accordingly your url
    $adminUrl='http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "", "password" => "");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                       
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type=> application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length=> ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);       
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token=  json_decode($token);

//Use above token into header
$headers = array('Authorization=> Bearer $token'); 

$requestUrl='http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products';
//Please note 24-MB01 is sku

$ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post ='{
  "product": {
    "sku": "MY_SKU",
    "name": "My Product",
    "attributeSetId": "4",
    "price": 20,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "typeId": "virtual",
    "weight": 0,
    "extensionAttributes": {
      "stockItem": {
        "stockId": 1,
        "qty": 20,
        "isInStock": true,
        "isQtyDecimal": false,
        "useConfigMinQty": true,
        "minQty": 0,
        "useConfigMinSaleQty": 0,
        "minSaleQty": 0,
        "useConfigMaxSaleQty": true,
        "maxSaleQty": 0,
        "useConfigBackorders": false,
        "backorders": 0,
        "useConfigNotifyStockQty": true,
        "notifyStockQty": 20,
        "useConfigQtyIncrements": false,
        "qtyIncrements": 0,
        "useConfigEnableQtyInc": false,
        "enableQtyIncrements": false,
        "useConfigManageStock": true,
        "manageStock": true,
        "lowStockDate": "string",
        "isDecimalDivided": true,
        "stockStatusChangedAuto": 0,
        "extensionAttributes": {}
      }
    },
    "options": [],
    "tierPrices": [],
    "customAttributes": [
    ]
  },
  "saveOptions": true
}';

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL=>$toURL,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post)),
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)",
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$post,

);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result=  json_decode($result);
print_r($result);


?>
```

the above code can not add product,i have try many method,still can not add product by rest api , anyone know how to add product by rest api?please help,Thanks.

the above code can not add product,i have try many method,still can not add product by rest api , anyone know how to add product by rest api?please help,Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
$url = domainname;
$token_url=$url."rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
$product_url=$url. "rest/V1/products";
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => username, "password" => password);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$adminToken=  json_decode($token);

$sampleProductData = array(
    'sku'               => $isbn13,
    'name'              => $name,
    'visibility'        => 4,
    'type_id'           => 'simple',
    'price'             => $price,
    'status'            => 1,
    'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
    'weight'            => $product_weight,
    'extension_attributes' => array(
            "stock_item"=>array(
                    'qty' => $inventory_stock,'is_in_stock' => 1,'manage_stock' => 1,'use_config_manage_stock' => 1,'min_qty' => 0,'use_config_min_qty' => 1,'min_sale_qty' => 1,'use_config_min_sale_qty' => 1,'max_sale_qty ' => 10,'use_config_max_sale_qty' => 1,'is_qty_decimal' => 0,'backorders' => 0,'use_config_backorders' => 1,'notify_stock_qty' => 1,'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 1
            ),
    ),
    'custom_attributes' => array(
        array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["43"] ),
        array( 'attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => $description ),
        array( 'attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => $short_description ),
        array( 'attribute_code' => 'meta_title', 'value' => $meta_title),
        array( 'attribute_code' => 'meta_keyword', 'value' => $meta_keyword),
        array( 'attribute_code' => 'meta_description', 'value' => $meta_description),
    ),
);

$productData = json_encode(array('product' => $sampleProductData));

$setHaders = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This is for product upload on magento 2 thorugh rest api Description = only copy code and put code in one php file and chagne domainname to (https://--------.com/) and after you create user and roles in magento 2(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMN-ZoeODlQ) and put that username in username field in this code and password also and run this code replace with all dynamic variable.(like $isbn13,$name...etc with your product detail ) see product is create or update in magento 2

Comment: Please provide some Description  too  with answer

Comment: yes please,
Question is on top so I placed only solutiion for that.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Question : Magento2 rest api how to add product? (this is question by user3404608) Answer : If you place this code and set related variable value than its working proper for add product API .

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     $adminUrl = 'http://localhost/magento2.1.2/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token/';
>     $ch = curl_init();
>     $data = array("username" => "", "password" => "");
>     $ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type=> application/json'));
>     $token = curl_exec($ch);
>     $token = json_decode($token);
> ```

use your magento admin username and password and get the token id.

Pass the $post json variable to this cURL call.

> ```
>        $curl = curl_init();
>        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
>        CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/magento2.1.2/index.php/rest/V1/products",
>         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
>         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
>         CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
>         CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
>         CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
>         CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
>         CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
>         CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
>             "authorization: Bearer $token",
>             "content-type: application/json"
>         ),
>     ));
>     $response = curl_exec($curl);
>     $err = curl_error($curl);
>     curl_close($curl);
>     if ($err) {
>         echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
>     } else {
>         echo $response;
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -2):

In request URL $requestUrl='http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products' change "products" to product and try.